# Dependency injection issue for `@ntegral/nestjs-sentry` package in nestjs app

Tags: nest, sentry

I am have an issue with this package `@ntegral/nestjs-sentry` in nestjs. I have a custom logger I use in my application

```js
@Injectable()
export class CustomLogger implements LoggerService {
  constructor(@InjectSentry() private readonly client: SentryService) {}

  log(message: any, ...optionalParams: any[]) {
    this.client.instance().captureMessage(message, ...optionalParams);
  }
}
```

I then inject the into User Controller and in the user.controller.spec.ts

```
describe('UsersController', () => {
  let controller: UsersController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [UsersController],
      providers: [
        CustomLogger,
        UsersService,
        SentryService,
      ],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get<UsersController>(UsersController);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

I get this error

```
 FAIL  src/users/users.controller.spec.ts (9.449 s)
  ● UsersController › should be defined

    Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CustomLogger (?). Please make sure that the argument Symbol(SentryToken) at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.

    Potential solutions:
    - If Symbol(SentryToken) is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
    - If Symbol(SentryToken) is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing Symbol(SentryToken) */ ]
      })
```

I have tried adding the `SentryService` to the spec providers but that does not fix the error. Has anyone encountered this and how did you fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I run in exactly the same issue. It seemed to be that the library uses a different token for its own Inject annotation. I was able to fix it in my tests by using the provided token for the SentryService mock.

```
import { SENTRY_TOKEN } from '@ntegral/nestjs-sentry';

// ...

const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  providers: [
  // ...
    {
      provide: SENTRY_TOKEN,
      useValue: { debug: jest.fn() }, // provide SentryService Mock here
    },
  ],
})
```

Comment: According to documentation of usage it would be more like: useValue: { instance: jest.fn() },

Comment: Of course, you need to mock all functions/attributes the Sentry class provides or at least the ones you are using (or use some library for automocking). The above object is just an example

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to get it work using:

cra.service.spec.ts

```js
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { SENTRY_TOKEN } from '@ntegral/nestjs-sentry';
import { AppLoggerService } from 'src/loggers/app-logger/app-logger.service';
import { CRAService } from './cra.service';

describe('CRAService', () => {
  let service: CRAService;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule, ConfigModule],
      providers: [
        CRAService,
        AppLoggerService,
        {
          provide: SENTRY_TOKEN,
          useValue: { debug: jest.fn() }, // provide SentryService Mock here
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<CRAService>(CRAService);
  });

  it('should be defined', async () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

My CRAServices looks something like:

```js
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { EnvironmentVariables } from 'src/configs/env.validation';
import { AppLoggerService } from 'src/loggers/app-logger/app-logger.service';

@Injectable()
export class CRAService {
  constructor(
    private readonly httpService: HttpService,
    private readonly configService: ConfigService<EnvironmentVariables>,
    private readonly logger: AppLoggerService
  ) {}
}
```